# Split strings separately between special characters in R

Tags: r

There is a string `dfdfd_666`. I am splitting this using below code

```
asd <- 'dfdfd_666'

substr(asd, 1, nchar(asd)-(1+nchar(gsub(".*\\_", "", asd))))
[1] "dfdfd"

gsub(".*\\_", "", asd)
[1] "666"
```

But if there are many such strings in a text. For example,

```
asd <- 'sdfgd_sdfgdsfg_hgfdsfg_gdhgfh_fghf'
```

Is there a way to split this separately and produce below

```
asd[1] <- sdfgd
asd[2] <- sdfgdsfg
asd[3] <- hgfdsfg
asd[4] <- gdhgfh
asd[5] <- fghf
```

and so on. The text can contain any thing like (gf_fghfd_dghfg_dfghf_fdgh_dfgh) . But the split should happen between `_`

Can anyone help to achieve this?

Below code splits it

```
strsplit("sdfgd_sdfgdsfg_hgfdsfg_gdhgfh_fghf", "_")
[[1]]
[1] "sdfgd"    "sdfgdsfg" "hgfdsfg"  "gdhgfh"   "fghf"
```

But it produces as a list and not able to retrieve each vectors

Comment: see ?strsplit .

Comment: `strsplit(asd, "_")`. Literally googling your title along with the quoted "R" as [`"R" Split strings separately between special characters`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22R%22+Split+strings+separately+between+special+characters) present many suggestions, some on StackOverflow, some "tutorials", etc.

Comment: I see this is the code ````strsplit(asd , split = "_")````. But the result produced is list. Not able to retrieve each element.  I have edited my question